# Error when using the els-cas template in Texmaker

Tags: errors, article, elsarticle, els-cas

I'm quite new to the `els-cas-dc` template in LaTeX. I want to submit a paper to Elsevier, thus I downloaded the "els-cas-templates" package. Specifically, my paper is a two column paper so I'm trying to use the els-cas-dc class. When I compile in TeXmaker on my MacBook, I get the following error message:

> "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/els-cas-templates/cas-
> dc.cls Error line 61 !LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found.Type X to
> quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension:
> sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. @ifundefined"

The following is the code I'm have written:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\sisetup{detect-all}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\emergencystretch=27pt %Allow 27pt of additional white space per line in order to avoid underfull/overfull lines
\hyphenpenalty=10000 %Prevent hyphenation if word is too long for line
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { stm / mktitle } { nologo }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\shorttitle{Adoption of Cocoa Agroforestry Technology and Productivity}
\shortauthors{Felix Larry Essilfie}
%\begin{frontmatter}

\title [mode = title]{Adoption of Cocoa Agroforestry Technology and Productivity: An Application of the Regression Adjustment Method with Weighting }
\author[1,2]{Felix Larry Essilfie}%[orcid=0000-0002-9398-9414]
%\author[1]{Nadeem Javaid*}
%\author[3]{Noor Islam}
%\author[1]{Khurram Saleem Alimgeer}
%\author[1]{Ammar Ali}
%\author[4]{Muhammad Riaz}
%\author[2]{Muhammad Usman}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cormark[1]
\ead{fessilfie@ideresearch.org}
\ead[URL]{www.ideresearch.org}
\address[1]{Institute of Development and Economic Research, No. 24 Bugatti St., Asheyie-Down, Adenta, Accra, Ghana}
\address[2]{Department of Agricultural Economics and Agribusiness, University of Ghana, Legon}
%\address[3]{CECOS University of IT \& Emerging Sciences, Peshawar 25124, Pakistan}
%\address[4]{Wah Engineering College, University of Wah, Wah Cantt 47070, Pakistan}
%and Khurram Saleem Alimgeer$^1$


\begin{abstract}[S U M M A R Y]
The study uses a sample of 1,175 cocoa farmers to assess the effects of cocoa agroforestry technology on the productivity of maize farmers. An approach that combines the regression adjustment method with weighting to estimate the treatment parameters was employed for the study. The approach is a generalization of the doubly robust estimation methods for different treatment parameters, which are defined in a multivalued treatment effect estimation framework.\par
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Short term load forecasting;competition-2012.
\end{keywords}
\maketitle
\section{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you on a current version of LaTeX? Your document compiles fine on my TexLive 2022 (Windows 10) setup.

Comment: How did you install the template? If using TeXlive or MacTeX, tlmgr should have installed all requirements for the package, but expl3.sty is a weird package not to have in any case, as it's a core package. Try to install it as well. (Your code works for me.)

Comment: Frabjous, I actually downloaded the template straight from CTAN and started running. Is there a I should have used to install it. I'm quite new to LaTeX anyways.

Comment: Ingmar, you are right. The code works fine for me when I run it in overleaf but does not when I run it via my TeXmaker on my MacBook. That is the strange thing here.

Comment: Hello comrades, I have reinstalled the l3kernel packages and now if I compile this I get this error: "! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.(LaTeX3) Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!(LaTeX3)(LaTeX3) The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format(LaTeX3) is dated 2022-04-29, but in your TeX tree the files require(LaTeX3) at least 2022-06-02.For immediate help type H <return>.... \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}" Any Help Please...

Comment: Installing things manually by downloading them from CTAN is almost never a good idea. You should install things using your distribution's package manager. Remove whatever packages you installed manually, run a tlmgr update and then try to install the templates with tlmgr as well. If that doesn't work you may need to reinstall TeXlive/MacTeX cleanly, but let's hope not.

Comment: It has worked out perfectly. Thank you